# None of my components will appear in my design (Android studio)

Tags: xml, android-studio, components, visibility, android-xml

So Im working on my first project in Android Studio, but I can no longer add components (textviews, buttons and so on...) to my one of my XML files. I can write the code for each component but my problem is that it wont appear on the design screen.

The strange thing is however that it works in my activity_main.xml, but not in my second XML file.

How do I make my textView appear on the design in my second XML file?
[image: My second XML file]

[image: My main enter image description here]

Here in my main XML file everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

On each component there is attributes, and on attributes under layout there is something called layout_height. I had selected "match_parent" which covered the entire screen and thats why no other component could appear.

To fix it, change "match parent" to "wrap content".

[image]